# Array modifier not duplicating around an empty

Tags: modifiers

I am very new to Blender but I have spent at least eight hours trying to solve my problem using You tube tutorials with no luck I am trying to use the array modifier to put treads around a torus. In edit mode I move it to where I want it. I select the tread object and add an array modifier. I set the count and it works like it should.Now I add an empty and select object mode and then I select the empty. If I rotate the empty now the tread object rotates but  now it's one object even though the count is set to 25.[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. When arrayed with modifier there won't be any individual objects and you can't edit them separately unless you apply modifier. If you want to spread objects with circular array make sure to put origin of the object to be arrayed in the same place as for the empty they are arrayed around